# How to retrieve parent object field values in SOQL to display in VF Page

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, soql

I am new to SFDC, struggling to retreive parent objects fields through SOQL query on child object.
I have two objects namely Opportunity and Scope where Scope has a lookup to Opportunity.

Here is the query i have written in Controller.

ScopeController.cls:

```
 List<Scope> scopeList=[Select  id,Name,ScopeValue__c,Opportunity__c,Opportunity__r.opAmount__c from Scope__c];
 System.debug('scopeList : '+scopeList);
```

Accessing the values of scopeList in below VF Page.

ScopePage:

```
 <apex:repeat value="{!scopeList}" var="s">
  <tr>
    <td>{!s.Name}</td>
    <td>{!s.ScopeValue__c}</td>
    <td>{!s.Opportunity__c}</td>
    <td>{!s.Opportunity__r.opAmount__c}</td>
 </tr>
</apex:repeat>
```

But in the above VF Page not able to show the value of s.Opportunity__r.opAmount__c, it is empty. I debugged in Controller, the SOQL query itself not retrieving the value of "Opportunity__r.opAmount__c" hence shown empty in VF Page.

Answer (score 0):

One reason could be that your profile does not have access to this field (Opportunity__r.opAmount__c).

Query looks fine to me. Do you see this value on the standard layout. Does your profile have access to this field?

1. From the management settings for the field’s object, go to the fields area.
2. Select the field you want to modify.
3. Click View Field Accessibility.